# Can't access Android SDK manager in Visual studio 2015

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I started few days back to learn android programming. I tried to use Eclipse and Android studio but I faced many problem (configuration) so I decided to develop android apps using XAMARIN/VS2015. I installed xamarin (android) but not android sdk manager because I installed it before using android studio. The problem is that I do not know how to link VS2015 to the previous android SDK manager already installed. Can anyone help me??
I know the folder where the sdk is unzipped in. It is even set in VS2015 but I have not idea why it is not working.
The following screenshot shows it clearly:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt299001.aspx .for set up Visual Studio and Xamarin & also https://docs.elementscompiler.com/VisualStudio/Setup/AndroidSDK/

Answer (score 1):

You need to link your sdk, not your adb.exe path.
I have this path for sdk:
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

[image]

You also can see this guide:

https://docs.elementscompiler.com/VisualStudio/Setup/AndroidSDK/

Comment: Can't see such option

Comment: I think you don't have necessary privileges